# Search array element in string swift 3.0

Tags: swift3

I want to search an element of an array of strings in a string. Like this:

```
let array:[String] = ["dee", "kamal"]
let str:String = "Hello all how are you, I m here for deepak."
```

so, I want

```
str.contain("dee") == true
```

any possible search in string?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one line by composing a regular expression pattern `"(item1|item2|item3)"`

```
let array = ["dee", "kamal"]
let str = "Hello all how are you, I m here for deepak."

let success = str.range(of: "(" + array.joined(separator: "|") + ")", options: .regularExpression) != nil
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the array and for each element, call `str.contains`.

```
for word in array {
    if str.contains(word) {
        print("\(word) is part of the string")
    } else {
        print("Word not found")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
array.forEach { (item) in
   var isContains:Bool = str.contains(item)
   print(isContains)
}
```